# How to create a maintenance page with a 503 code in Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-hosting

Using the following `firebase.json`, I'm able to redirect users to my desired `maintenance.html` page. However, the page is retrieved with a 304 status code. I would like it to be retrieved with a 503 status code to indicate to a search engine that this is temporary maintenance. I've attempted to set the header manually but it doesn't appear to work. How can this be accomplished in Firebase?

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [],
    "redirects": [ {
      "source": "/index.html",
      "destination": "/maintenance.html",
      "type": 307
    } ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**"
        , "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/maintenance.html",
        "headers": [ {
          "key": "status",
          "value": "503"
        } ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [],
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/index.html",
        "destination": "/maintenance.html",
        "type": 307
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/maintenance.html",
        "headers": [ {
          "key": "status",
          "value": "503"
        } ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted, but the headers configuration is not working for me. Firebase is returning two status code in the header:
status: 200
status: 503

Comment: @Fnop did you add the 307 redirect for your index page?

Comment: @murty did you just remove `rewrites`, that's all?

Comment: Sorry @benomatis this was a long time ago and I don’t remember beyond the details in my answer.